# Handle Errors & Execute Try Again in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to process through my `try` loop again after an error has been found and handled by `except (AttributeError)`. Right now, the script ends after an error is handled rather than starting from the `try` loop. Any help getting back to the `try` loop after an error is encountered would be greatly appreciated.

```
try:
    #code
except (AttributeError) as error:
    print (error)
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "try loop"

Comment: @That1Guy What's the `try` block of statements called then?

Comment: What you have is a `try...except`. Nothing is looping, it tries what is in the `try` block and excepts the exceptions you specify.

Comment: @That1Guy Is there any way to iterate over the `try` block again after an error is excepted?

Comment: wrap everything in a while loop?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen good idea, I'm just trying to think of a conditional that would end the `while` loop when it's done processing many files in a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    try:
        #code
    except AttributeError as error:
        print(error)
    else:
        break
```

Control goes to the else block only if there is no exception in the try block.
Check this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You could create a while loop that encompasses everything:

```
while True:
    try:
        #code
        break
    except (AttributeError) as error:
        print (error)
```

I added a break at the end of the try statement because I am under the assumption that once all the try code successfully runs you would like that section to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
retry = False
try:
    #code
except AttributeError as error:
    print error
    retry = True
finally:
    if retry:
        #code
```